# Insert date and time whenever a procedure starts and end and its total count in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for which I want to insert its date and time that when that procedure was executed and also how many counts of row was inserted.

`TBL_SIGNOFF_ACT_CNT` is the table where I want to insert the date, time, count... for the below procedure.

```html
create or replace PROCEDURE FIBER_SIGNOFF_UGAR_UPD AS 
VSQLERR varchar2 (200);
VSQLERRCODE varchar2 (200);
v_ne_length number;
v_ug_length number;
v_ar_length number;
vper number;
cmpapprvlen number;
v_actual_ug_length number;
v_actual_ar_length number;

vcircle nvarchar2 (100);
vMpname nvarchar2 (100);
vMpcode nvarchar2 (100);
vspanlinkid nvarchar2(100);
vspantype nvarchar2(100);
vnelength number;

BEGIN

 execute immediate 'delete from APP_FIBERINV.TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET';

for cur_r in (
                   SELECT CIRCLE, 
                          regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,1)MPNAME,
                          regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,2)MPCODE,
                          SPAN_LINK_ID,
                          SPAN_TYPE,
                          NE_LENGTH,
                          ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM AS CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH
                          FROM APP_FIBERINV.TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV 
                          where (CMM_APPROVED_DATE IS NOT NULL OR ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 0 OR JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1)
              )
              
loop

begin
      vcircle := cur_r.CIRCLE; vMpname := cur_r.MPNAME; vMpcode := cur_r.MPCODE; vspanlinkid := cur_r.SPAN_LINK_ID; vspantype := cur_r.SPAN_TYPE; vnelength := cur_r.NE_LENGTH;
      cmpapprvlen:=cur_r.CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH;
          IF vspantype = 'INTERCITY' AND length(vspanlinkid) = 21              
             THEN             
             BEGIN
             --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start '||vspantype||vspanlinkid); 
             SELECT ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH, 
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' AND RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL  THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LENGTH
                   ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LENGTH
                  
                  into v_ne_length, v_ug_length, v_ar_length
                   FROM ne.mv_span@db_link_ne_viewer
                   WHERE RJ_SPAN_ID = vspanlinkid
                  AND (RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID NOT LIKE ('%\_9%') ESCAPE '\' OR RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL) 
                   and  INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
                   and  RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = vMpcode;            
                  
                   if(v_ne_length > 0 or cmpapprvlen > 0) then 
                    vper:= (v_ug_length / v_ne_length)*100;  
                    
                    v_actual_ug_length:= (cmpapprvlen*vper)/100;
                    v_actual_ar_length:= cmpapprvlen-v_actual_ug_length;                 --
                    else
                     v_actual_ug_length:= cmpapprvlen;
                     v_actual_ar_length:= 0;   
                   end if;
                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CALC '||v_actual_ug_length||v_actual_ar_length); 
    
                 INSERT INTO APP_FIBERINV.TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET (FSA_UG, FSA_AERIAL, CIRCLE, MAINTENANCEZONENAME, MAINTENANCEZONECODE, SPAN_LINK_ID, SPAN_TYPE,NE_LENGTH, HOTOOFFERDATE)
                           VALUES (v_actual_ug_length, v_actual_ar_length, vcircle, vMpname, vMpcode, vspanlinkid, vspantype,vnelength, SYSDATE);

                COMMIT;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTED'); 
                EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  
                  v_actual_ug_length:=cmpapprvlen;
                  v_actual_ar_length:=0;
                  v_ne_length:=0; v_ug_length:=0; v_ar_length:=0;

                WHEN OTHERS THEN    
                    VSQLERRCODE:= SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 5);
                    VSQLERR:= SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
                     INSERT INTO SIGNOFF_SHEET_ERR (err_code,err_msg,err_date) VALUES ('db:scheduler',VSQLERRCODE||':'||VSQLERR,SYSDATE);
                     COMMIT; 
                  --ROLLBACK;
                   
             END;
             
          ELSIF vspantype = 'INTERCITY' AND length(vspanlinkid) = 9             
             THEN
             BEGIN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start '||vspantype||vspanlinkid); 
                SELECT ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH, 
                     ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LENGTH
                   ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LENGTH
                  into v_ne_length, v_ug_length, v_ar_length
                   FROM ne.mv_span@db_link_ne_viewer
                   WHERE RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = vspanlinkid
                   and  INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
                   and  RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = vMpcode; 
                    
                   
                  if(v_ne_length > 0  or cmpapprvlen > 0) then 
                    vper:= (v_ug_length/v_ne_length)*100;  
                    
                    v_actual_ug_length:= (cmpapprvlen*vper)/100;
                    v_actual_ar_length:= cmpapprvlen-v_actual_ug_length;                 --
                    else
                     v_actual_ug_length:= cmpapprvlen;
                     v_actual_ar_length:= 0;   
                   end if;
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CALC '||v_actual_ug_length||v_actual_ar_length); 
                    
                 INSERT INTO APP_FIBERINV.TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET (FSA_UG, FSA_AERIAL, CIRCLE, MAINTENANCEZONENAME, MAINTENANCEZONECODE, SPAN_LINK_ID, SPAN_TYPE,NE_LENGTH, HOTOOFFERDATE)
                           VALUES (v_actual_ug_length, v_actual_ar_length, vcircle, vMpname, vMpcode, vspanlinkid, vspantype,vnelength, SYSDATE);

                COMMIT; 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTED'); 
                EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  
                  v_actual_ug_length:=cmpapprvlen;
                  v_actual_ar_length:=0;
                  v_ne_length:=0; v_ug_length:=0; v_ar_length:=0;

                WHEN OTHERS THEN     
                    VSQLERRCODE:= SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 5);
                    VSQLERR:= SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
                     INSERT INTO SIGNOFF_SHEET_ERR (err_code,err_msg,err_date) VALUES ('db:scheduler',VSQLERRCODE||':'||VSQLERR,SYSDATE);
                     COMMIT;   
                
             END;
             
          ELSIF (vspantype = 'INTRACITY' OR vspantype = 'ENTERPRISE')
             THEN
             BEGIN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start '||vspantype||vspanlinkid); 
                SELECT ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH, 
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LENGTH
                   ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LENGTH
                  into v_ne_length, v_ug_length, v_ar_length
                   FROM ne.mv_span@db_link_ne_viewer
                   WHERE RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = vspanlinkid
                    and  INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
                   and  RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = vMpcode; 
                   
                  if(v_ne_length > 0  or cmpapprvlen > 0) then 
                    vper:= (v_ug_length/v_ne_length)*100;  
                    
                    v_actual_ug_length:= (cmpapprvlen*vper)/100;
                    v_actual_ar_length:= cmpapprvlen-v_actual_ug_length;                 --
                    else
                     v_actual_ug_length:= cmpapprvlen;
                     v_actual_ar_length:= 0;   
                   end if;

                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CALC '||v_actual_ug_length||v_actual_ar_length); 
                  INSERT INTO APP_FIBERINV.TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET (FSA_UG, FSA_AERIAL, CIRCLE, MAINTENANCEZONENAME, MAINTENANCEZONECODE, SPAN_LINK_ID, SPAN_TYPE,NE_LENGTH, HOTOOFFERDATE)
                   VALUES (v_actual_ug_length, v_actual_ar_length, vcircle, vMpname, vMpcode, vspanlinkid, vspantype,vnelength, SYSDATE);
                  COMMIT; 
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTED'); 
                  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  
                      v_actual_ug_length:=cmpapprvlen;
                      v_actual_ar_length:=0;
                      v_ne_length:=0; v_ug_length:=0; v_ar_length:=0;

                  WHEN OTHERS THEN     
                     VSQLERRCODE:= SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 5);
                     VSQLERR:= SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
                     INSERT INTO SIGNOFF_SHEET_ERR (err_code,err_msg,err_date) VALUES ('db:scheduler',VSQLERRCODE||':'||VSQLERR,SYSDATE);
                     COMMIT; 
             END;
        end if;
        
     EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN    
                    VSQLERRCODE:= SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 5);
                    VSQLERR:= SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
                     INSERT INTO SIGNOFF_SHEET_ERR (err_code,err_msg,err_date) VALUES ('db:scheduler',VSQLERRCODE||':'||VSQLERR,SYSDATE);
                     COMMIT; 
                     
end;           


end loop;



END FIBER_SIGNOFF_UGAR_UPD;
```

also desc of `TBL_SIGNOFF_ACT_CNT` table is

```
Name          Null? Type            
------------- ----- --------------- 
ERROR_MESSAGE       NVARCHAR2(2000) 
INSERT_COUNT        NUMBER
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to learn from us. What exactly is the problem you cannot solve?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: there is no problem. i just want to track when the above procedure ran and it should records its time and date in the table mentioned. Also the count of how many records got inserted

Comment: Yes, but you probably know how to insert a row into a table and you know that sysdate and sysdatetime exist, so what keeps you from inserting the rows at the start and end of your procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `COUNT` you can use below.

```
V_NUMBERVARIABLE:= SQL%ROWCOUNT;
```

At the end of your procedure before `EXCEPTION` part. You can use below `INSERT INTO` syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_SIGNOFF_ACT_CNT
(
   ERROR_MESSAGE   NVARCHAR2 (2000),
   INSERT_COUNT    NUMBER
);


DECLARE
   V_ROWCNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   V_ROWCNT := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

   INSERT INTO TBL_SIGNOFF_ACT_CNT
        VALUES ('Proc started: ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), V_ROWCNT);

   COMMIT;
   
   ...
   ...
   
   V_ROWCNT := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

   INSERT INTO TBL_SIGNOFF_ACT_CNT
        VALUES ('Proc end: ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), V_ROWCNT);

   COMMIT;
END;
```

[Here is a link of my solution:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6c5540ff586ae9fad3d7ff40505605f7)

[And this one is your solution updated:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81da80ff95da3fd02652c555dfd9bbea)

[image]

Comment: but where exactly i should add this code.. and i want date time also

Comment: Edited check it. @hud

Comment: i have updated with your code in my SP.. please have a look is it okk https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f13a71ef00603dddddec0ff17756d981

Comment: It's ok. But i revise my code that you can also add hour:minutes:seconds `YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS` @hud

Comment: ohh. can u update that in the link which i provided so it would be better for me ?

Comment: does it track start date and end date both ? if not how can we insert end date..

Comment: You can add one insert at the beginning of your procedure and one insert at the end. This way when it started first insert would be your start and last insert would be your end. @hud

Comment: i executed my procedure but its always showing `proc started` with `0` row count. also in my main table the records are inserted `79` records

Comment: also its showing me `79` rows inserted in `TBL_SIGNOFF_ACT_CNT` table but with `0` insert_count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220014/discussion-between-hud-and-ismetguzelgun).